# Creating system call in Minix3

Tags: minix

I have a problem about system call in minix3.I have to create a system call which is called "deneme" and when i execute  this system call, it should print the content of top command (for example. PID,usernama,size ..).
Can anyone prepare a list for the steps.I made somethings but I get error in makefile files.

Comment: Please share the somethings that you made, and what error(s) they generated.

Comment: I used that document http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/nick.cook/csc2025/minix/syscall-exercise1.html.I get some error  when i execute "make services" command